Ollama Embeddings: Are the embeddings in the same order as the documents?
I’m using OllamaEmbeddings from langchain_community.embeddings (in Python) to generate embeddings of documents. I need to be absolutely sure that the embeddings are in same order as the documents that I passed in. For example, the first embedding returned by OllamaEmbeddings has to correspond to the first document, the second embedding has to correspond to the second document, and so on. My question is whether the order of the embeddings generated by OllamaEmbeddings is the same as the order of the documents passed into OllamaEmbeddings. I couldn’t find information about that in the API reference or anywhere else. I'm not using Chroma, so I can't use Chroma.from_documents().
I looked at the API reference for OllamaEmbeddings and many other sources; none of them mentioned it.
Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The input list of documents and the output list of embeddings are in the same order. See functions
_self._embed and embed_documents in the following link.
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/_modules/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.html#OllamaEmbeddings
